# How can I level my bed?

Tags: bedroom, level

I have a very uneven floor in my bedroom, and a metal bed frame (non-leveling feet), soon to be a wooden bed frame. I'd like to level my bed. What are some good ways to do this?

One approach is to just get some shims and stack them up. If this is my best bet, then what are recommended materials to use?

I'm surprised to not find more discussion about this problem on the web -- it's really unhealthy to sleep on an unlevel bed, and many floor in old houses are very unlevel.

Comment: Depends on just how non-level the floor is. I expect that the only way I could do it would be to build a level platform, ripping its understructure to the appropriate sizes/angles to provide the needed support, and then put the bed on top of that.

Comment: Can you install some [cabinet levelers](http://www.busybeetools.com/product_images/7/1107/B2509_zoom.jpg) or [furniture levelers](http://files.catalog-on-demand.com/XDSAssetStore/ebbrad/Graphic/Product/pm300z2_specs.jpg)? They are meant to adjust to uneven floors.

Comment: _" it's really unhealthy to sleep on an unlevel bed"_ - I'd like to see your sources.

Comment: Someone I know had ongoing trouble sleeping and hit upon the idea of making the bed non-level, raising the head of the bed 1.5 inches.  The slope has proved much healthier than a level bed.

Comment: For folks with chronic acid reflux, it's often recommended for them to sleep on a slight incline.

Comment: You might get better answers, if you indicate just how uneven your floor is.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the degree to which the bed posts are out of level, the floor type you are using and the diameter of the post contact on the ground.

It sounds like you are going wood posts, what I would do there is to get a few Cork or rubber Adhesive floor protectors (like below)

The problem there, is that you need to find material which is slightly thicker than your gaps, since you cannot really add these things together too much (since they will be easy to fall off) - You can also attempt to slit them with a long stanley blade. these strips will needed to be applied to the underside of each bed post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a drop ceiling tile. Cut it to an appropriate size and slid it under each foot that needed adjusting. If necessary, stack two and place under the feet that need more height. They adjust the bed height with pressure of your body. This really works.

Answer (score 0):

Try these adjustable feet.  They are cheap and can be screwed directly into your bed frame if wood.  If metal use the angle/flange of your rail system and use an appropriate adjustable style foot to screw/bolt into then adjust until there's no more rocking.

http://www.homedepot.com/s/adjustable%2520feet?NCNI-5